# Targeting a specific child of this.props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `<Panel />` component structured like this:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

export default class Panel extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        children: PropTypes.object,
        scrollable: PropTypes.bool,
        swipeable: PropTypes.bool
    };

    static defaultProps = {
        scrollable: true,
        swipeable: false
    };

    render() {
        const styles = require('./Panel.css');

        const {
            children,
            scrollable
        } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className={styles.Base}>
                { scrollable ?
                    <div className={styles.ScrollArea}>{children}</div>
                    : {children}
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

It’s basically just a wrapper component that will usually contain a list of scrollable items. I use it like this:

```
<Panel>
    <ul className={styles.FontMenu}>
        { fonts.map((font) => {
            return (
                <li
                    key={`font-menu-${font.id}`}
                    className={selectedFamily.id === font.id ? styles['FontMenuItem--isActive'] : styles.FontMenuItem}>
                    {font.label}
                </li>
            );
        })}
    </ul>
</Panel>
```

I occasionally need to be able to scroll to a specific item in the list when the panel mounts. I know the index of the item I’d like to scroll to, and I’d like to add a method to the `<Panel />` component that takes a `scrollTo` prop as an attribute using that index, but since the items in the list are dynamic children I’m not sure what might be a smart way to implement.

How can I easily target the dynamic children of a component and get their properties?

Comment: [Refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) aren't helping here?

Comment: When I set a ref on the `<li />` it’s only available in the parent component that contains `<Panel />` and not in the `<Panel />` component, right? My whole thing is that I want the `scrollTo` method to be part of the `<Panel />` component.

Comment: I suppose you could use React.Children.toArray to get a reference to the child component (see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children).

Comment: Oh that’s a fabulous idea, @bryanph. Mind adding it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm uncertain how to implement a solution to your problem because I can't tell how scrollTo is set.  If it's set based on child attributes, then you might want to set custom attributes on the children using cloneElement in your Panel's render():

```js
render(){
 return (
   <div>
     {this.renderChildren()}
   </div>
   
   )
  
}

renderChildren(){
  return React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child){
    if (child.property1 === 'scrollHere'){
      return React.cloneElement(child, { shouldScrollToHere: true })
      else return child
    }.bind(this))
  }
```

Then in componentDidMount() of the Panel, maybe you can look at the children and scroll to the proper item, using setState perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to define a separate higher-order component that wraps the given child component allowing you to pass in a focus prop that indicates whether to focus the given component or not:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'

var FocusWrapper = function(Component) {
    return (props) => (
        <Component {...props} ref={(c) => {
            if (props.focus) {
                c.focus()
            }
        }}
    )
}

FocusWrapper.PropTypes = {
    focus: PropTypes.bool
}
```

Then you can wrap whatever component needs a focus method based on its props and use the wrapped component in the main component.